# how to make SSRS 2012 Report server url as SSL

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

To debug the SSRS webservice2010 method (logonUser) need Report Server as SSL.

How to display Installed certificate in the Reportingservice Congifuration manager-->WebserviceURL menu-->Advanced button -->Certificate list

kindly provide steps to create and install Trusted certificate for SSRS report 2012.

Comment: Did you try to create your own certificate? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345223(v=sql.120).aspx has the list of steps for configuring SSL connections in SSRS 2012. After you've tried, If you have a specific problem we'd be happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Certificate created and installed in trusted rool .Configured in Reporting service configuration manager.
to create certificate - I used makecert.exe from visual studio command prompt.
and installed the certificate using mmc(management console).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your certificate created ,import it into the mmc using below steps :

To add the Certificates snap-in to an MMC for a computer account
1.Click Start, type mmc in the Search programs and files box, and then press ENTER.

2.On the File menu, click Add/Remove Snap-in.

3.Under Available snap-ins, double-click Certificates.

4.Select Computer account, and then click Next.

5.Do one of the following: 
◦ To manage certificates for the local computer, click Local computer, and then click Finish.

◦ To manage certificates for a remote computer, click Another computer, and then type the name of the computer, or click Browse to select the computer name, and then click Finish.

6.If you have no more snap-ins to add to the console, click OK.

7.To save this console, on the File menu, click Save.

Now open the console and follow below steps :

A. Expand Certificates Node; 
 B. Right click Personal -> All Tasks -> Import.

Once the certificate is imported it will appear in the drop down of advanced tab in the url section.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754431(v=ws.11).aspx